# How can I determine the absolute position of an element within an iframe taking in to account the frame's scroll in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know the absolute position (pixels from top and left) of a HTML element within an iFrame that has scrolled. I've tried using the `findpos` script from quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html):

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        }
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return [curleft, curtop];
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to account for the fact that the iFrame may have scrolled. How can I modify this script to account for the scroll of the iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

```
function findPosRelativeToViewport(obj) {
    var pos= findPos(obj);
    var root= document.compatMode=='BackCompat'? document.body : document.documentElement;
    pos[0]-= root.scrollLeft;
    pos[1]-= root.scrollTop;
    return pos;
}
```

(the compatMode stuff being to cater for IE in Quirks Mode. But don't use Quirks Mode.)